what's the difference between 再 and 更，一点
i saw phrases 再好也没有了 and 他的打字速度可以再快了一点儿
i know that 再 means "again" or "then", but i take it in these cases that means smth like "more"?
then, what's the difference between this pattern and others meaning "more"?
can i use it with every adjective (like 再漂亮 or whatever) or there's limited quantuty of them?
and one more thing, can it be used for comparison with a specific object? like 我比你再有钱?




From Xinhua Dictionary
In "我比你再有钱" . "比" is 谓语, so "再有钱" must be 补语 . But in the dictionary, if we want to use the "more" meaning , we can see that "再" is a 副词 , but if without 动词 or 形容词 , 副词 can't be 补语 . In "再有钱" ,we can discover that it can be divided into two parts , which is "再",“有钱”. In it , "有钱" is 谓语 . So , just from the grammar , "我比你再有钱" has no mistake.
But in habit , "......比......更......" is a fixed sentence pattern . But in China , we have no sentences useing "......比......再......"

一点 generally means "a little" and does not mean 更 or 再
A lot of English people do say things like "more good" or "more better". You shouldn't really use "more" with simple adjectives or superlatives in English, because, for example, "better" means: "more good" an increase of good over just "good" and "more" requires a noun: "More pudding, Madam?"
good, better, best
?? more good, more better, more best ??
But this is not a problem in Chinese: 再好, 更好
再: 副词。
①表示又一次：再接再厉。一错再错。reduplicate, repeat
②表示事情或行为重复、继续，多指未然：明天再来。雨不会再下。  repetition or continuation
③用在两个动词之间，表示动作的先后关系：做完作业再去玩。 repeat or continue after doing something else
④更，更加：再好没有了。  more
⑤表示加外有所补充：再则。  moreover, furthermore
You can see from ④ that 再 and 更 can have the same meaning.
生活可是好得不能再好了。
Life couldn't be better.
如果你明天回来，也许更好。
Perhaps it would be better if you came back tomorrow.
再好也没有了
Maybe (it was) good, but there is still none left
他的打字速度可以再快了一点儿.
His typing could be a little faster.

再 = 更 - more
再好也没有了 = 没有比這個更好的了 - nothing is more better than this.

你能來那再好也没有了 - Nothing is more better than you can come.

他的打字速度可以再快一点儿 = 他的打字速度可以更快一点儿. - His typing speed could be more fast/much faster.

練習/訓練後, 他的打字速度可以再快一点儿 - After practice/training, his typing speed could be more fast/much faster.

(不論/即使/縱然)再 - no matter/regardless how

再漂亮也不能當飯吃 - No matter/regardless how pretty, it can't fill the stomach.

再有錢也買不到真情 - No matter/regardless how rich, it can't buy true love.



and one more thing, can it be used for comparison with a specific object? like 我比你再有钱?

No, if you meant "I am much more rich than you - 我比你更有錢". But, "yes", if you mean "no matter/regardless how much I am richer than you.... - 不論我比你再有钱...."
